# Easy way to transform data frame in R - one variable values as separate columns

Tags: r, dataframe

What I have (obviously I'm presenting a very small fraction of my current data):

```
my_df <- structure(list(X = structure(c(48.75, 49.25), .Dim = 2L), Y = structure(c(17.25, 17.25), .Dim = 2L), Time = structure(c(14625, 14626), .Dim = 2L, class = "Date"), spei = c(-0.460236400365829, -0.625695407390594)), .Names = c("X", "Y", "Time", "spei"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

What I need:

```
new_df <- structure(list(X = structure(c(48.75, 49.25), .Dim = 2L), Y = structure(c(17.25, 17.25), .Dim = 2L), "2010-01-16" = c(-0.460236400365829, NaN), "2010-01-17" = c(NaN, -0.625695407390594)), .Names = c("X", "Y", "2010-01-16", "2010-01-17"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

What is the easiest way of doing this?
I thought about writing a for loop, but I guess that apply/sapply might help on this?

[image: transformation needed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use library `tidyr` and its `spread` function like this:

```
library(tidyr)
spread(my_df, Time, spei)
      X     Y 2010-01-16 2010-01-17
1 48.75 17.25 -0.4602364         NA
2 49.25 17.25         NA -0.6256954
```

Comment: I like this solution more than reshape. However, is there any parameter to sort columns by date in spread?

Comment: You can use use `order` or `dplyr` packages `arrange` to pre-sort the data frame on date column and then do spread.

Answer (score 2):

Without any additional packages you could do that with `reshape()`:

```
reshape(my_df, idvar = c('X', 'Y'), timevar = "Time", direction = 'wide')
```

Which gives:

```
      X     Y spei.2010-01-16 spei.2010-01-17
1 48.75 17.25      -0.4602364              NA
2 49.25 17.25              NA      -0.6256954
```